# CORS issue on localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have real struggle with PayPal-node-SDK npm module. It can not redirect me to paypal page and the error the `Failed to load https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=******: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.` And I read the world about this problem, but I couldn't find a fix for it. So I am using react with webpack dev server for the FE part and I have node.js/express api which makes my connection to the paypal sdk. In my code you can see that the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is allowed, but still I have CORS error. Here is my configuration for the webpack dev server:

```js
    devServer: {
        contentBase: Path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
        historyApiFallback: true,
        port: 3000,
        proxy: {
            "/api/*": { target: 'http://localhost:5000', secure: false, changeOrigin: true }
        },
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
        }
    }
```

and here is my node.js api:

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');

// Paypal module configuration
paypal.configure({
  'mode': 'sandbox', //sandbox or live
  'client_id': '*********',
  'client_secret': '**********'
});

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.post('/api/paypal-payment', (req, res) => {
        var create_payment_json = {
          "intent": "sale",
          "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
          },
          "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": "http://localhost:3000/paypal/success",
            "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/paypal/cancel"
          },
          "transactions": [{
            "item_list": {
              "items": [{
                "name": "Some Name",
                "sku": "some-sku",
                "price": "1",
                "currency": "USD",
                "quantity": 1
              }]
            },
            "amount": {
              "currency": "USD",
              "total": "1"
            },
            "description": "Some Description"
          }]
        };

        // Make the payment to paypal with the parameters added above
        paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
          if (error) {
            console.log('error', error);
          } else {
            console.log(payment);
            for (let i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
              if (payment.links[i].rel === 'approval_url') {
                res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);
              }
            }
          }
        });
    }
  );

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

and this is my axios request to the API:

```js
export const handlePayment = (months) => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios.post('/api/paypal-payment, {
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      }
    })
      .then(res => dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data }))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }
}
```

I tried everything, but with no luck, so every suggestion will be appreciated. Any ideas how I can fix this CORS problem? Thank you guys!

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set on response https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: What does `changeOrigin: true` do?

Answer (score -1):

`CORS` have too part in here, first `axios` will intercept `CORS` request, and then the server should allow origin. you can check which part in `Network` module of `Developer Tools`.

allow axios `CORS` request

```
 axios.post('/api/paypal-payment', {
    withCredentials: true
 })
```

Comment: Hey @Cr. I tried the change that you shared here, but still no luck.

Comment: Check `Network` in `Developer Tools` to confirm does the request be sent out? And what it response?

Answer (score -2):

Try adding this plugin [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) if you are using chrome.
It allows you to bypass cors check by adding * to the header in the request.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This might be something one could do temporarily in development, but isn't a deployable solution.  You don't want to require someone have a browser plug-in installed in order to by something on your site.

Comment: I agree with @jfriend00, there should be some way for easy deployment and maintenance. There is no scale when you install chrome plugin, what if other developer is using FF as a development browser, but still I wouldn't vote down, because it still a legit answer.

Comment: The question was “cors issue on localhost”, when he takes it to production this won’t be an issue because he will be querying from a valid URL?